# Parsing Variables from console error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fairly new to python and need a little guidance.  I'm trying to pass some variables from the console and get and error message:

`AuctionStrategy_2.0.py: error: argument -s/--sectorStocks: invalid int value: 'tep3'`

when I run the console command:

```
 run AuctionStrategy_2.0.py -in10 -out5 -rolls15 -step3 -t.001 -s5 -m100 -v50 -e'01/01/2016'
```

Could someone let me how to fix this please?  My code at the moment does nothing except try and pass the variables from the console.  Please see below for my code:

```
import argparse
import os
import fnmatch
import pandas as pd 
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
import lzma
import numpy as np
import math
import datetime

def main():
    print('Processing args....')   

    insampleLength,outsampleLength,rolls,step,threshold,minStocksPerSector,minMarketCap,minVolume,endDate = get_args()
    print(insampleLength,outsampleLength,rolls,step,threshold,minStocksPerSector,minMarketCap,minVolume,endDate)
    rawDataPath = 'C:/Users/simon/Documents/data/close_unadjusted/close_unadjusted/'

def get_args():

    '''This function parses and return arguments passed in'''

    insampleLength = 0
    outsampleLength = 0
    rolls = 0
    step = 0
    endDate =''
    minStocksPerSector = 0
    threshold = 0


    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Args to run VWAP Auction simulation')

    ''' Command line arguments'''

    parser.add_argument('-in', '--inSampleDataLength', type=int, help='Number of historic epochs insample', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-out', '--outSampleDataLength', type=int, help='Number of historic epochs outsample', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-rolls', '--numberRolls', type=int, help='Number of rolls', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-step', '--rollStep', type=int, help='Number of historic epochs', required=True)

    parser.add_argument('-t','--threshold', type=float, help='starting value', required=True)    
    parser.add_argument('-s','--sectorStocks', type=int, help='minimum number', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-m','--marketCapCutOff', type=int,help='market capitalisation', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-v','--volumeCutOff', type=int, help='daily volume', required = True)
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--endDate', type=str,help='last day of testing',required = True)


    args = parser.parse_args()

    ''' Assign args to variables'''

    insampleLength = args.inSampleDataLength
    outsampleLength = args.outSampleDataLength
    rolls = args.numberRolls
    step = args.rollStep
    threshold = args.threshold
    minStocksPerSector = args.sectorStocks
    minMarketCap = args.marketCapCutOff
    minVolume = args.volumeCutOff
    endDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(args.endDate, "%d-%b-%Y")


    return insampleLength,outsampleLength,rolls,step,threshold,minStocksPerSector,minMarketCap,minVolume,endDate


if __name__ == "__main__":  
    print ("AuctionStategy_1.0...25/03/16")

    try:
        main()              
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("Ctrl+C pressed. Stopping...")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single dash always identifies a single-character argument. But you are trying to define `-step`; this is interpreted as `-s`, which is redefined later by the actual `-s` argument.

You should either pick a different identifier for "step", or always use the double-dash version `--rollStep`.

Answer (score 0):

The argument `-s` expects an integer, you gave a string, this causes the error you get.

BTW, I think it's better to add spaces between the names of the arguments and it's values, e.g.:

```
run AuctionStrategy_2.0.py -in 10 -out 5 -rolls 15 -step 3 -t .001 -s 5 -m 100 -v 50 -e '01/01/2016'
```

Hope this helps